PowerBI: Row Level Security with not all users in Table
I have a question regarding RLS.  I have a table which I want to use the RLS on for an APP in Power BI and I do not want to create more than 1 role but instead have 1 Role manage all users.  The issue I am having is that there is not 1 source combined or otherwise that has all possible users so the source table has the set of users that are to be secured and any one else is "open" or full access.
enter image description here
To secure the users that need to be secured I have
[user_name] == USERPRINCIPALNAME()

but what I would like to do is something like this instead:
[user_name] == 
IF(Not(USERPRINCIPALNAME() in {'prd RLS_Owner'[user_name]}),
"All",
USERPRINCIPALNAME()) 

I have tried reversing it and every other which way that I can think of doing it.
I have attached a picture of the table
[user_name] == 
IF(Not(USERPRINCIPALNAME() in {'prd RLS_Owner'[user_name]}),
"All",
USERPRINCIPALNAME()) 

